# How to correctly include local libraries in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, include

I have a PyCharm project, which can be simplified to

```
src/code1.py
lib/lib1.py
lib/lib2.py
```

Following autocomplete suggestions from PyCharm, I have written the includes as follows:

`code1.py`:

```
from lib import lib1
```

`lib1.py`:

```
from lib import lib2
```

The code works fine in PyCharm. But when I run it with simple python, I get the error `No module named 'lib'`. How do I write my includes in a way that is consistent between PyCharm and regular Python

Comment: shouldn't it be `from lib import lib1` ?

Answer (score 0):

pycharm handle the project structure well, when you run the application in simple terminal you face challenge in running program as there is no project struture linking.

to replicate this in simple python terminal , run the program from the base folder .

as per your requirement i suggest you to keep all the core component in the lib directory and above that you code file.

else you can create a package type structure where every component start from base directory,

since you want to run individaual files seperatly, i sugget you to use code1.py outside of src folder in the base folder. adding the file structure

[image]

test\lib__init__.py

```
       from . import lib1, lib2
```

test\lib\lib1.py

class Lib1():
    def **init**(self):
        pass
    def hello(self):
        return "hello world"

test\lib\lib2.py

```
class Lib2():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def hello(self):
        return "hello world"
```

test__init__.py

```
from . import lib
```

test\code1.py

```
from lib import lib1
x = lib1.Lib1()
print(x.hello())
```

After this you can run test\code.py

otherwise if you want to maintain your code structure then

[image]

in test\src\code1.py file

```
import os, sys

from os.path import dirname, join, abspath
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), '..')))

from lib import lib1
x = lib1.Lib1()
print(x.hello())
```

after this u can use `python test\src\code1.py` directly

Comment: I thought this was the case, but I still get the error mentioned above

Comment: Can you try to replicate the exact file structure I have proposed, only having includes in file texts, and then tell me if it works for you running it from the base directory

Comment: @prashaht Thank you so much for your effort, but this is not exactly what I have asked. Can you run the command `python test/src/code1.py` without getting an error?